# Cannot start SQLEXPRESS services

Tags: sql, sql-server, service

I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 recently. But I cannot connect to database, and I found the problem.

The problem is SQL Server (`SQLEXPRESS`) service is not started.

I try to start it, but it comes to nothing. I check Event Viewer, and I got the message but I don't know how to fix it.

Please help me. Thanks a lot guys.

[image]

This is from the Event Viewer Log

```
FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(failed to retrieve text for this   error. Reason: 15105)
occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf'. 
Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
```

and this is error log from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log`

```
2014-05-31 11:26:12.54 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (Intel X86) 
Mar 29 2009 10:27:29 
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7600: )

2014-05-31 11:26:12.54 Server      (c) 2005 Microsoft Corporation.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.54 Server      All rights reserved.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.54 Server      Server process ID is 4560.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.55 Server      System Manufacturer: 'SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.', System Model: '300E4C/300E5C/300E7C'.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.55 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.55 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.55 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 1688 at 31/05/2014 11:20:48 (local) 31/05/2014 4:20:48 (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.55 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
 -d c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
 -e c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
 -l c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2014-05-31 11:26:12.58 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.58 Server      Detected 2 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.63 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.70 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x00000003 Active CPU mask: 0x00000003. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.75 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.92 spid7s      FILESTREAM: effective level = 0, configured level = 0, file system access share name = 'SQLEXPRESS'.
2014-05-31 11:26:12.97 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2014-05-31 11:26:12.97 spid7s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.00 spid7s      The resource database build version is 10.00.2531. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.17 spid7s      Server name is 'MARTIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.17 spid10s     Starting up database 'model'.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.17 spid7s      Informational: No full-text supported languages found.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.17 spid7s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.86 Server      A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.86 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].
2014-05-31 11:26:13.86 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ].
2014-05-31 11:26:13.86 Server      Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.87 Server      The SQL Server Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Error: 0x54b, state: 3. Failure to register an SPN may cause integrated authentication to fall back to NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.87 Server      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.94 spid10s     Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.94 spid10s     FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100).
2014-05-31 11:26:13.94 spid10s     Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.94 spid10s     Unable to open the physical file "e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf". Operating system error 21: "21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)".
2014-05-31 11:26:13.95 spid7s      Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.95 spid7s      FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBData.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
2014-05-31 11:26:13.95 spid7s      Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
2014-05-31 11:26:13.95 spid7s      Unable to open the physical file "e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBData.mdf". Operating system error 21: "21(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)".
2014-05-31 11:26:15.57 spid10s     Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-05-31 11:26:15.57 spid10s     FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
2014-05-31 11:26:15.57 spid10s     File activation failure. The physical file name "e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\modellog.ldf" may be incorrect.
2014-05-31 11:26:15.57 spid10s     Error: 945, Severity: 14, State: 2.
2014-05-31 11:26:15.57 spid10s     Database 'model' cannot be opened due to inaccessible files or insufficient memory or disk space.  See the SQL Server errorlog for details.
2014-05-31 11:26:15.57 spid10s     Could not create tempdb. You may not have enough disk space available. Free additional disk space by deleting other files on the tempdb drive and then restart SQL Server. Check for additional errors in the event log that may indicate why the tempdb files could not be initialized.
2014-05-31 11:26:15.57 spid10s     SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2014-05-31 11:26:15.58 spid7s      Error: 17207, Severity: 16, State: 1.
2014-05-31 11:26:15.58 spid7s      FileMgr::StartLogFiles: Operating system error 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) occurred while creating or opening file 'e:\sql10_main_t\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\MSDBLog.ldf'. Diagnose and correct the operating system error, and retry the operation.
Cannot close event log because there are still event handle users active.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems in the startup log. It may be simply easier to install a new instance than the fix your messed up instance though.

You must have a model database. Your startup log shows that is it apparently missing. Did you attempt to move SQL datafiles files to a different location? If not, don't know why you would be having these problems. If you don't have a copy to model.mdf & model.ldf you can copy them from another computer running the same version of sql.

See [for an article](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=187922) that steps you through "fixing" the location of the model database.

This [article](http://www.sql-server-citation.com/2012/03/moving-msdb-to-new-location.html) is essentially the same kind of article, but it is for msdblog.

Of course, you have to adjust the file references to match your local setup.

Once you have these database files fixed, you can likely start management studio.